# How many criminal exiles were sent to Kamchatka?

Tags: 19th-century, russia, 18th-century, crime, kamchatka

[Exile in Siberia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katorga) was a well-known punishment for criminals in Imperial (and Soviet) Russia. Exiles, who could be common criminals or political prisoners, were forced to walk in irons to their new job at a mine or saltworks. The more remote labor camps cost the state more. James Gibson wrote in *Feeding the Russian Fur Trade* that the exiles were "state servitors" and that:

> ... the worst offenders, such as traitors and murderers, were banished to the northern and eastern extremities of Siberia, including the [Okhotsk] seaboard and the [Kamchatka] peninsula, while lesser offenders were exiled to less remote and more civilized parts.

Under the rule of Catherine the Great (1762-1796), how many criminal exiles were sent all the way to Kamchatka? I can only name [Benyovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Benyovszky).